# You can't select item 'org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle.model.OraclePackage@7affaF26- WHILE Selecting Packages FOR Schema Compare

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, liquibase, dbeaver, cicd

I'm new to Dbeaver, trying to use this for the Azure CICD process for oracle.
While comparing the schema it only compares the table, views, materialized views, and types
but when I select packages it's not allowed to throw below error.
[image]
I'm using Liquibase + Dbeaver to achieve this.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If so, could you share the solution?